# AngularJS $timeout executes immediately in safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, safari

I am having a weird issue with `$timeout` in AngularJS that only occurs in Safari (both iOS and macOS), but not in other browsers. Instead of waiting the specified milliseconds, Safari executes the function immediately. The entire code is available [here](https://github.com/tjespe/Superpache/blob/master/.src/js/upload-widget.js), but this is the relevant part of the code:

```
app.directive('upload', ['$lhttp', '$http', '$interval', '$timeout', '$q', '$location', function ($lhttp, $http, $interval, $timeout, $q, $location) {
    return {
      templateUrl: '/.src/views/upload-widget.html',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      // code ...

      // Define upload function
      vm.uploadFiles = ()=>{
        // code ...

        // Create the payload for the upload request
        let formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("salt", salt);
        // code ...

        // Create the upload request
        let request = $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: "/.src/php/upload.php",
          data: formdata,
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          uploadEventHandlers: {
            progress: function(e) {
              vm.progress = Math.round((e.loaded/e.total)*100) + "%";
              if (vm.progress === '100%') vm.get_server_progress(salt);
            }
          },
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        });

        // Create handler functions for success and errors
        request.then(function successCallback (response) {
          vm.server_progress = "100%";
          vm.actually_loading = false;
          $timeout(()=>{ vm.loading = false }, 600);
          if (response.data.error.length) {
            vm.fail = true;
            vm.error_message = response.data.error;
          }
          if (!response.data.log.length) {
            vm.fail = true;
            vm.error_message = $scope.m.text.upload_error;
          }
        }, function errorCallback (response) {
          // code ...
        });
      }

      // code ...

      // Create function for checking status of server side processing of the upload
      vm.get_server_progress = (salt)=>{
        $http.get('/.src/php/status.php?salt='+salt+'&d='+Date.now()).success((data)=>{
          vm.server_progress = data+"%";
          re_get_progress_if(salt);
        }).error(()=>{
          re_get_progress_if(salt);
        });
      }

      function re_get_progress_if (salt) {
        //////////////////////////////////////
        // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC $TIMEOUT://
        if (vm.actually_loading) $timeout(vm.get_server_progress, 100, true, salt);
      }
    },
    controllerAs: 'up'
  };
}]);
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug in Safari? If it is, how can I do a workaround?

Comment: You're sure that it's immediate? Have you tried a larger value for delay, like 5000? The other timeout works in Safari?

Comment: did you try increasing to an higher value? and did you try if you have the same issue using the standard `setTimeout` of JS?